# Передать параметр в REST controller

Tags: java, angularjs, rest

Столкнулся с задачей в вебприложении - при смене email у юзера необходимо запросить пароль. С написанием бэкенда проблем нет (пишу на java), с ангуляром пока плаваю. 
Метод изначально принимал только email.

Добавил в метод 
`var passConfirm = vm.passwordConfirmEmail;`
В следующей строках где `console.log` мыло и пароль отображается.

Вызываю свой рест `UserExt.updateEmail.query...`

```
function saveEmail() {
        var mod = vm.emailMod;
        var passConfirm = vm.passwordConfirmEmail;

        console.log(mod);
        console.log(passConfirm);

        UserExt.updateEmail.query(mod, function (res) {
            console.log("------query updateEmail-------");
            if (!res || !res.code) {
                $scope.toastr.error('error.occured');
                return;
            }
            var code = res.code;
            console.log(code);

            if (code === 'INCORRECT_EMAIL') {
                $scope.toastr.error('error.incorrect-email');
            } if (code === 'INCORRECT_EMAIL_OR_PASS') {
                $scope.toastr.error('error.incorrect-email-or-password');
            }
            else if (code === 'EMAIL_EXISTS') {
                $scope.toastr.error('msg.email-exists');
            } else if (code === 'EMAIL_CHANGED') {
                $scope.toastr.success('msg.email-changed');
            } else {
                $scope.toastr.error('error.occured');
            }
        }, function () {
            console.log("fail***********************");
            $scope.toastr.error('error.occured');
        });
    }
```

REST

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users-ext/updateEmail",
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<CodeDto> updateEmail(@RequestBody User user) throws URISyntaxException {
```

.....

Изначально в параметр принимал `@RequestBody String email`

Как в ангулар-функцию определить параметр `passConfirm` что бы его передать дальше в REST Controller? Сейчас приходит null, уверен что лажа в "моем" ангуляре

Comment: Так вы шлете объект mod на сервер, который не может сериализоваться в сущность User. Сделайте класс User в ангуляре, набор которых соответствует ожидаемому User на серверной стороне, а дальше джексон джейсон сам десериализует значение, которое будет приходить с фронта

Comment: спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

ответ был довольно как оказалось прост, необходимо было создать переменную юзера и в точности отобразить поля обьекта:

```
function saveEmail() {
        var user = {
            'email':vm.emailMod,
            'password':vm.passwordConfirmEmail
        };

        UserExt.updateEmail.query(user, function (res) {
        .....
        .....
```